# only remove characters from substring if substring is longer than x in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have string of words and wish to remove the "ay" from the end of a word only if the word exceeds 4 characters.

For example:

```
"I work every day except monday, tuesday, wednesday and thursday"
```

should return :

```
"I work every day except mond, tuesd, wednesd and thursd"
```

I'm sure this can be solved using the string.replace() method, I just need to figure out what can be added to the (/ay$/gi, "") to make it only replace ay for words with more than 4 characters while being able to handle commas and spaces.

Comment: @torazaburo that also matches "day" which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The `/ay$/gi` regex will only match `ay` at the end of any words.

You can use the following code:

```js
var re = /\b(\w{3,})ay\b/gi;  // It will match `ay` at the end of a 5+ letter word
var str = 'I work every day except monday, tuesday, wednesday and thursday';
var result = str.replace(re, '$1');
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

The regex is `\b(\w{3,})ay\b`. It matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w{3,})` - 3 or more alphanumeric symbols and **stores them in Group 1** (we'll backrefence the value stored in this [**capture group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) later in the replacement string)
- `ay\b` - matches `ay` at the end of the word.

The `$1` [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) in the replacement string *gets* the value stored in Capture group 1 buffer (that is, what was captured by `(\w{3,})`, 3 or more alphanumeric symbols).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT4xK0/3)

Comment: I think it should be (\w{3,}) because it needs to *exceed* 4 characters

Comment: Yes, fixed that right now. Usually, when a threshold is mentioned, I assume it is included. :(

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, please could you explain these parts: `var re = /\b(\w{2,})ay\b/g; `and `'$1'`. Thanks!

Comment: I added some more explanation and links to the regular-expressions.info Web reference where you can read more about capturing and backreferences. The `(...)` are just  a means of matching specific subpatterns and store them in some buffer that we can access from the replacement pattern using backreferences.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev! What about the `$1` in `str.replace(re, '$1')`?

Comment: `$1` is a backreference: in `Monday`, it *extracts* `Mond` from capture group #1 as it was submatched by `\w{3,}` and inserts that into the replacement result.